# What does 'skip in test' do in build.sbt?

Tags: sbt

I found this in the root `build.sbt`

```scala
skip in test := true
```

What does it do? I cannot find any reference regarding this in sbt documents. I'm using sbt 1.3.8 in my Scala project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If set to `true`, the `test` task won't run and no test will be executed.

In your context, no test of the root project will be executed.

One way to know what the task is doing and how it used by other tasks is to run `inspect` task.

```
sbt "inspect test:skip"
```

Produces:

```
[info] Task: Boolean
[info] Description:
[info]  For tasks that support it (currently only 'compile', 'update', and 'publish'), setting skip to true will force the task to not to do its work.  This exact semantics may vary by task.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  Global / skip
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults.globalSbtCore) Defaults.scala:294
[info] Delegates:
[info]  Test / skip
[info]  Runtime / skip
[info]  Compile / skip
[info]  skip
[info]  ThisBuild / Test / skip
[info]  ThisBuild / Runtime / skip
[info]  ThisBuild / Compile / skip
[info]  ThisBuild / skip
[info]  Zero / Test / skip
[info]  Zero / Runtime / skip
[info]  Zero / Compile / skip
[info]  Global / skip
[info] Related:
[info]  Global / skip
```

With description

> For tasks that support it (currently only 'compile', 'update', and 'publish'), setting skip to true will force the task to not to do its work.  This exact semantics may vary by task.

Comment: Thanks! Do you also have some links to the sbt reference for skip? I cannot find it.

Comment: It's mentioned in the [Publishing documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Publishing.html#Skip+publishing), not sure if there are any other mentions of it